# Наследование width

Tags: javascript, html, css

Доброго времени суток) 
При использовании процентной записи ширина элемента вычисляется в зависимости от ширины родительского элемента.

Хорошо!

Kак cделать, что бы ширина дочернего элемента в процентах вычислялась не по ширине родительского, а по ширине родительского блока его родителя!

Например

```
 <div class="main_slider">
   <div class="sliders">
        <div class="img slide">  //что бы width(%) наследовался не от sliders, a от main_slider
           <img src="Page_bridge.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="des">
             <p>Good Inc. image caption to go here</p>
          </div>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Или это невозможно?

Comment: Если только использовать js

Comment: @Yuri поддай идею?

Comment: В общем случае никак, в конкретном - надо думать. В приведённом примере недостаточно данных. [Вот тут](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428584/178988) не получилось.

Answer (score 3):

Изменять нужно только в CSS проценты :)

```js
$(function() {
  var e = $('.three'), p0 = $('.two'), p1 = $('.one');
  var w = (e.outerWidth() / p0.outerWidth()) * p1.outerWidth();
  e.css({width: w});
});
```

```css
.one {width:300px;height:50px;border:1px solid #000}
.two {width:50%;height:50px;background-color:black}
.three {width:40%;height:50px;background-color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
    <div class="three">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: а если в первом блоке(.one) стоит width: 100%, все так и остается?

Comment: Да. Только этот код работает, если в `.three` ширина указана процентами. Если пикселями, то оно некорректно будет выводить

Comment: я понял) То есть по сути получается адаптивность?

Comment: @Nick, получается :)

Answer (score 0):

Ну если я правильно понял, то вот так -

```css
.first {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  
  background: pink;
  
  position: relative;
}

.second {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  
  background: orange;
}

.third {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  
  background: tomato;
  
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <div class="second">
    <div class="third"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно реализовать таким способом, при этом, можно вытаскивать данные любого элемента на странице:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.one {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #eee;
}
.two {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
}
.three {
  background: #000;
  height: 100px;
}
@element ".one" {
  .three {
    width: 20ew;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/eqcss/1.4.0/EQCSS.min.js"></script>
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
    <div class="three">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Регулируется значением `width: 20ew;`, что соответсвует 20% от выбранного элемента.

Comment: А это какой язык?

Comment: Это JavaScript plugin. Подробнее можете почитать [тут](http://elementqueries.com/), прада на английском.